# Get distinct rows from multiple LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, distinct

Here is my `match` table

```
+----------------------------+
|Match_id |team1_id|team2_id |
------------------------------
|    1    |   1    |    2    |
+----------------------------+
```

Teams have severals played mapped by team_player

```
+------------------+
|team_id |player_id|
--------------------
|    1    |   1    |
|    1    |   2    |
|    1    |   3    |
|    2    |   4    |
|    2    |   5    |
|    2    |   6    |
+------------------+
```

And then the `players` table

```
+----------------------+
|player_id |player_name|
-----------------------|
|    1     |   p1      |
|    2     |   p2      |
|    3     |   p3      |
|    4     |   p4      |
|    5     |   p5      |
|    6     |   p6      |
+----------------------+
```

I try to get players name by team. Here is my query :

```
SELECT tp1.`player_id` as id1, tp2.`player_id` as id2, p1.`player_name` as pseudo1, p2.`player_name` as pseudo2
FROM (`match` m
LEFT JOIN `team_player` tp1 ON m.`team1_id` = tp1.`team_id`
LEFT JOIN `team_player` tp2 ON m.`team2_id` = tp2.`team_id`)
LEFT JOIN `players` p1 ON tp1.`player_id` = p1.`player_id`
LEFT JOIN `players` p2 ON tp2.`player_id` = p2.`player_id`
WHERE m.`MATCH_ID`= 49
```

It gets me this :

```
+------------------------+
|id1 |id2|pseudo1|pseudo2|
|------------------------|
|1   |4  |   p1  | p4    |
|1   |5  |   p1  | p5    |
|1   |6  |   p1  | p6    |
|2   |4  |   p2  | p4    |
|2   |5  |   p2  | p5    |
|2   |6  |   p2  | p6    |
|3   |4  |   p3  | p4    |
|3   |5  |   p3  | p5    |
|3   |6  |   p3  | p6    |
+------------------------+
```

Is it possible to get this :

```
+------------------------+
|id1 |id2|pseudo1|pseudo2|
|------------------------|
|1   |4  |   p1  | p4    |
|3   |5  |   p2  | p5    |
|1   |6  |   p3  | p6    |
+------------------------+
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: because i newb in mysql, maybe, my answer will be more understandable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-trivial result. I'd prefer to use two separate statements, to get the two separate team lists, and handle the formatting of the two results together in the client, rather than using a single SQL statement.

But, if I had to generate this result using a single SQL statement, I would do it like this, using inline views, with user-defined variables to generate a "row number" value for each team list... combine the two team lists with a UNION ALL, and use a `GROUP BY` row number to combine the rows, and conditions in the SELECT list to pick out the values for team1 and team2 columns.

```
   SELECT MAX(IF(s.tn='1',s.id    ,NULL)) AS id1
        , MAX(IF(s.tn='2',s.id    ,NULL)) AS id2
        , MAX(IF(s.tn='1',s.pseudo,NULL)) AS pseudo1
        , MAX(IF(s.tn='2',s.pseudo,NULL)) AS pseudo2
     FROM ( 
            ( SELECT @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 AS rn
                   , '1'              AS tn
                   , tp1.player_id    AS id
                   , p1.player_name   AS pseudo
                FROM (SELECT @rn1 := 0 ) i1 
                JOIN `match` m1 ON m1.match_id   = 49
                JOIN team_player tp1 ON tp1.team_id = m1.team1_id
                LEFT JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = tp1.player_id 
               ORDER BY p1.player_id
            )  
            UNION ALL    
            ( SELECT @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 AS rn
                   , '2'              AS tn
                   , tp2.player_id    AS id
                   , p2.player_name   AS pseudo
                FROM (SELECT @rn2 := 0 ) i2 
                JOIN `match` m2 ON m2.match_id   = 49
                JOIN team_player tp2 ON tp2.team_id = m2.team2_id
                LEFT JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = tp2.player_id 
               ORDER BY p2.player_id
            ) 
          ) s
    GROUP BY s.rn
    ORDER BY s.rn
```

[**SQL Fiddle demomonstration here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61dd4/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61dd4/2)

Comment: I don't understand how it works, but it's perfect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should join 'team_player' only once, e.g.

```
tp ON  tp.`team_id` in (m.`team1_id`, m.`team2_id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id1, id2, pseudo1, pseudo2
  from
    (select @n:=@n+1 n, tp.player_id id1, player_name pseudo1 
       from 
         (select @n:=0) n, 
         (`team_player`tp 
            join `players` p 
              on p.`player_id` = tp.`player_id`)
      where team_id = 
         (select team1_id from `match` where Match_id = 49)) as sel1 
   join 
    (select @m:=@m+1 m, tp.player_id id2, player_name pseudo2 
       from 
         (select @m:=0) m, 
         (`team_player`tp
             join `players` p 
               on p.`player_id` = tp.`player_id`)
       where team_id = 
          (select team2_id from `match` where Match_id = 49)) sel2
   on n = m
```

result

```
id1  id2  pseudo1  pseudo2
1    4    p1       p4
2    5    p2       p5
3    6    p3       p6
```